# mongodb $lookup return empty array

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongodb and in this question I have 2 collections, one is selected_date, another is global_mobility_report, what I'm trying to do is to find entries in global_mobility_report whose date is in the selected_date so I use $lookup to join the two collections.

date_selected:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f60d81ba43174cf172ebfdc"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-22T00:00:00.000+08:00")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f60d81ba43174cf172ebfdd"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-23T00:00:00.000+08:00")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f60d81ba43174cf172ebfde"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-24T00:00:00.000+08:00")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f60d81ba43174cf172ebfdf"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-25T00:00:00.000+08:00")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f60d81ba43174cf172ebfe0"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-26T00:00:00.000+08:00")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f60d81ba43174cf172ebfe1"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-05-27T00:00:00.000+08:00")
}
```

global_mobility_report:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f49fb013acddb5eec37f99e"),
    "country_region_code" : "AE",
    "country_region" : "United Arab Emirates",
    "sub_region_1" : "",
    "sub_region_2" : "",
    "metro_area" : "",
    "iso_3166_2_code" : "",
    "census_fips_code" : "",
    "date" : "2020-02-15",
    "retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline" : "0",
    "grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline" : "4",
    "parks_percent_change_from_baseline" : "5",
    "transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline" : "0",
    "workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline" : "2",
    "residential_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f49fb013acddb5eec37f99f"),
    "country_region_code" : "AE",
    "country_region" : "United Arab Emirates",
    "sub_region_1" : "",
    "sub_region_2" : "",
    "metro_area" : "",
    "iso_3166_2_code" : "",
    "census_fips_code" : "",
    "date" : "2020-02-16",
    "retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1",
    "grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline" : "4",
    "parks_percent_change_from_baseline" : "4",
    "transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1",
    "workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline" : "2",
    "residential_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f49fb013acddb5eec37f9a0"),
    "country_region_code" : "AE",
    "country_region" : "United Arab Emirates",
    "sub_region_1" : "",
    "sub_region_2" : "",
    "metro_area" : "",
    "iso_3166_2_code" : "",
    "census_fips_code" : "",
    "date" : "2020-02-17",
    "retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline" : "-1",
    "grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1",
    "parks_percent_change_from_baseline" : "5",
    "transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1",
    "workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline" : "2",
    "residential_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f49fb013acddb5eec37f9a1"),
    "country_region_code" : "AE",
    "country_region" : "United Arab Emirates",
    "sub_region_1" : "",
    "sub_region_2" : "",
    "metro_area" : "",
    "iso_3166_2_code" : "",
    "census_fips_code" : "",
    "date" : "2020-02-18",
    "retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline" : "-2",
    "grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1",
    "parks_percent_change_from_baseline" : "5",
    "transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline" : "0",
    "workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline" : "2",
    "residential_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1"
}
```

when I try to find all entries in global with 'date' match in selected_date(I have converted the string to data format in gobal_mobility_report), it returns empty array.

```
db.global_mobility_report.aggregate([
{$match:{country_region:"Indonesia"}},  
{$addFields: {"dateconverted": {$convert: { input: "$date", to: "date", onError:"onErrorExpr", onNull:"onNullExpr"}:}}},
{
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "selected_date",
         localField:"dateconverted",
         foreignField: "date",
         as: "selected_dates"  // empty
       }
})]
```

The output is:

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f49fd6a3acddb5eec4427bb"),
        "country_region_code" : "ID",
        "country_region" : "Indonesia",
        "sub_region_1" : "",
        "sub_region_2" : "",
        "metro_area" : "",
        "iso_3166_2_code" : "",
        "census_fips_code" : "",
        "date" : "2020-02-15",
        "retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline" : "-2",
        "grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline" : "-2",
        "parks_percent_change_from_baseline" : "-8",
        "transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1",
        "workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline" : "5",
        "residential_percent_change_from_baseline" : "1",
        "dateconverted" : ISODate("2020-02-15T08:00:00.000+08:00"),
        "selected_dates" : [ ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f49fd6a3acddb5eec4427bc"),
        "country_region_code" : "ID",
        "country_region" : "Indonesia",
        "sub_region_1" : "",
        "sub_region_2" : "",
        "metro_area" : "",
        "iso_3166_2_code" : "",
        "census_fips_code" : "",
        "date" : "2020-02-16",
        "retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline" : "-3",
        "grocery_and_pharmacy_percent_change_from_baseline" : "-3",
        "parks_percent_change_from_baseline" : "-7",
        "transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline" : "-4",
        "workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline" : "2",
        "residential_percent_change_from_baseline" : "2",
        "dateconverted" : ISODate("2020-02-16T08:00:00.000+08:00"),
        "selected_dates" : [ ]
    }
```

Comment: Don't attach images, you should post codes

Comment: Can you post the both collection data

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an empty array is because `dateconverted` does not match the `date` field.

The `$lookup` operator does an equality between the `localField` and the `foreigntField` field, so basically with an example

```js
db.users.insertMany([
    { email: "test@example.com", userId: 0  },
    { email: "test2@example.com", userId: 1 },
    { email: "test3@example.com", userId: 2 },
    { email: "test3@example.com", userId: 3 }
]);

db.posts.insertMany([
    { by: 0,  post: "hello world" },
    { by: 0 , post: "hello earthlings" },
    { by: 3,  post: "test test test"}
]);
```

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "by",
        foreignField: "userId",
        as: "list_of_post"
    }
    }
]).toArray();
```

The output will be what it suppose to be, because the localField matched the ForeignField

```js
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f6859a6df3133b325eb0"),
        "by" : 0,
        "post" : "hello world",
        "list_of_post" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f6849a6df3133b325eac"),
                "email" : "test@example.com",
                "userId" : 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f6859a6df3133b325eb1"),
        "by" : 0,
        "post" : "hello earthlings",
        "list_of_post" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f6849a6df3133b325eac"),
                "email" : "test@example.com",
                "userId" : 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f6859a6df3133b325eb2"),
        "by" : 3,
        "post" : "test test test",
        "list_of_post" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f6849a6df3133b325eaf"),
                "email" : "test3@example.com",
                "userId" : 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Let's mimic a situation where it does not match

```js
db.posts.drop();
db.posts.insertMany([
    { by: 20,  post: "hello world" },
    { by: 23 , post: "hello earthlings" },
    { by: 50,  post: "test test test"}
]);
```

We get an empty array

```js
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f83344304796ae700b4d"),
        "by" : 20,
        "post" : "hello world",
        "list_of_post" : [ ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f83344304796ae700b4e"),
        "by" : 23,
        "post" : "hello earthlings",
        "list_of_post" : [ ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f60f83344304796ae700b4f"),
        "by" : 50,
        "post" : "test test test",
        "list_of_post" : [ ]
    }
]
```

So, back to your question, the reason for the empty array is as a result of the `dateconverted` field not matching the `date` field. So, let's take a look at an example.

In the first document the `dateconverted` is
`ISODate("2020-02-16T08:00:00.000+08:00")` and checking at date_selected document , there is no field that correspond to this value `ISODate("2020-02-16T08:00:00.000+08:00")`. But let's manually insert this, so you will properly understand what I am talking about.

```js
db.date_selected.insert({
  "_id" : ObjectId(), 
  "date": ISODate("2020-02-16T08:00:00.000+08:00")
});
```

Running the aggregation pipeline will also make `selected_dates` an empty array. And the other thing you have to note is that the `mm/dd/yyy` part of the `ISODate` object does not also match any document in your question. Secondly, you have to devise another means of running the comparison, because the aggregation pipeline in the $addFileds stage will be affected by timezone and other issues as well.

Comment: Very clear! What I want to match is only the date, while what the script does is matching the exact time! Got it! Thanks very much!

Comment: @QianWu Kindly upvote the answer and accept the answer if it helped you figure out the issue